# how to implement a progress bar in react?

Tags: reactjs, antd

[image]

I want to make this component, both the start and end point should move continuously, when the end point reaches the end, it should start from beginning. I am currently using antD  progress bar.
Was thinking to use requestAnimationtionFrame , but the value isn't getting updated

My Ques are these:

1. How to move the start point ?
2. How to make this continuous?

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (loading == true && loadingPercent != 100) {
        if (loadingPercent > 90) {
            setPercent(0);
        }
        const percentage = setTimeout(() => {
            setPercent(loadingPercent + 40);
        }, 1);
        return () => {
            clearTimeout(percentage);
        };
    }
}, [loadingPercent]);

<Progress showInfo={false} percent={loadingPercent} size="small" />
```

I was trying with this but didn't work

```
const changePercent = () => {
    console.log(loadingPercent);
    if (loading === false) {
        console.log(loadingPercent);
        return;
    } else {
        if (loadingPercent < 99.9) {
            const rotation = loadingPercent + 50;
            setPercent(rotation);
            console.log(loadingPercent);
        } else {
            setPercent(0);
        }
        if (loading == true) requestAnimationFrame(() => changePercent());
    }
};
```

**Note**: I wan't to start this loading whenever `loading == true`

Comment: I think you might have a better time implementing this with CSS animations, and the result will likely be more fluid too.

Answer (score 2):

### You can try on this way

**in Progressbar component**

```
return (
<div className="progress-outer">
  <div
    className={`progress ${size ? "progress--" + size : ""} ${
      isLoading ? "progress--" + "loading" : ""
    }`}
  >
    <div className={`progress-bar`} style={{ width: percent + "%" }}></div>
  </div>

  {isLoading == false && showInfo ? (
    <span className="progress-info">{percent}%</span>
  ) : (
    ""
  )}
</div>
```

);

**in your component from call progressbar like this**

```
<ProgressBar
    isLoading={true}
    percent={50}
    size={"medium"}
    showInfo={false}
 />
```

you change status depend on your data/api response.

also, find out more this link: [Live demo codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-cloud-ze9w7?file=/src/ProgressBar.js)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use mui design system with react

https://mui.com/

this api: https://mui.com/components/progress/#linear

example:

```
<LinearProgress />
```